# Issue with conversion to razor syntax for model binding of jQuery generated dynamic textboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I need to model-bind data from textboxes generated dynamically on the client side (using jQuery .tmpl plugin) so that the data is accessible in my MVC3 controllers. I found code for this at the following link:

http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/ASPNET-MVC-Binding-to-Listse28093Enumerables-on-POST-with-JQuery.aspx

This article discusses several approaches alongwith working source code. The last approach is what I want and it works. But it is probably using the webforms view engine (inside JavaScript blocks) or just server side tags. I would appreciate if someone can help me get it working with razor syntax.

In particular I was hoping to get the razor syntax for the following block in the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%int idx=0;
      foreach (var c in Model){ 
        ViewData["key"]=idx; %>
        $("#ClientTemplate").tmpl([{FirstName : "<%: c.FirstName %>",  
                                    LastName : "<%:c.LastName %>" ,
                                    idx: <%:idx.ToString()     %>}]).appendTo("#ExistingClients");
        <% idx++;%>
    <%} %>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeClient(DivName) {$("#" + DivName).remove();}
    var num = <%:Model.Count() %>;
    $("#btnAddNewClient").click(function () {
        $("#ClientTemplate").tmpl([{FirstName : "",  
                                    LastName : "" ,
                                    idx: num}]).appendTo("#NewClients");
        num++;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get it working in the manner I had thought earlier. I ended up creating a javascript object with the same property names as my C# object and then sending the object to the controller method using a jquery .ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{
        int idx = 0;
        foreach (var c in Model)
        {
            ViewData["key"] = idx; 

            <text>
                $("#ClientTemplate").tmpl([{FirstName : "@c.FirstName",  
                    LastName: "@c.LastName" ,
                    idx: @idx.ToString()}]).appendTo("#ExistingClients");        
            </text>

            idx++;
        } 
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeClient(DivName) {$("#" + DivName).remove();}
    var num = @Model.Count();
    $("#btnAddNewClient").click(function () {
        $("#ClientTemplate").tmpl([{FirstName : "",  
                                    LastName : "" ,
                                    idx: num}]).appendTo("#NewClients");
        num++;
    });
</script>
```

---

I find that temporarily removing the script tags can help prevent VS2010s razor parser getting itself confused.